# Show top subdomains from google analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, wpmu

How can I output a list of i.e. top 20 subdomains from my google analytics account in my website sidebar?

reason: I'm using WPMU and want to create a toplist of bloggers by visitornumber.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much functionality the Google Analytics Management Api provides but it seems like you can extract some data on your accounts ...

[Analytics Management Api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/)

[Analytics Management Api rest service](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtRest)

Comment: thanks for the info, but i didnt find any usefull info matching my knowlage :(